# Configure Firebase Function to accept HAL+JSON as request body

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When using HTTP-triggered Functions in Firebase, I'm unable to access a HAL+JSON payload from the HTTP request.

The request looks like:

```
POST /endpoint
Content-Type: application/hal+json

{ /* some payload */ }
```

In my function I'm accessing the payload using `request.body`, like this:

```
...
var myPayload = request.body;
...
```

The value of myPayload is:

```
{}
```

Instead, when the HTTP request contains `Content-Type: application/json`, the value of `myPayload` is the correct one:

```
{ /* some payload */ }
```

I believe it's related to the following: [express.json()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

Is there a way to configure express in Firebase to include `application/hal+json`? For example:

```
express.json({
  type: [ 'application/json', 'application/hal+json' ]
});
```

Or to access the raw body myself?

Note: I don't want to create an express app within the function.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests) for understanding how Cloud Functions automatically processes incoming requests.

> Cloud Functions parses request body content types of application/json
>   and application/x-www-form-urlencoded according to the rules described
>   above. Plain text content types (text/plain) are passed through as
>   strings using UTF-8 as a default encoding (or a custom encoding
>   provided in the content-type header).
>
> For other content types, the rawBody property contains the unparsed
>   bytes of the request body as a Buffer object.

Your "other content type" here probably means that your raw request body will be available from the Request object in the `rawBody` property.

Comment: Thanks @doug-stevenson. Unfortunately, when using `Content-Type: application/hal+json` it doesn't work: `req.rawBody` is `undefined`. If I try `Content-Type: text/plain` then `req.rawBody` contains a buffer. Looks like there is no parser setting `req.rawBody` when the payload is HAL+JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to access the current express app and do the following?
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-json#change-content-type-for-parsers

Comment: What about this one? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36252545 Apparently the solution described in comment #39 hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce.  When I send data to a simple https function that logs both `body` and `rawBody`, and invoke it with curl, I see both values.  `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"message":"Hello World!"}' https://us-central1-.../myFunctions`

Comment: If you think there's still a problem, please provide the exact code and repro instructions that anyone can use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me on the local emulator. Versions in use: firebase:^4.6.0, firebase-admin:^5.5.1, firebase-functions:^0.7.5. But it does work on the cloud, that's not good. Should I raise a bug for it?

Comment: I think it's a known issue that the emulator works slightly differently than the actual Cloud Functions runtime.  Feel free to log the bug though and add your voice.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/